# Count number of new lines outside double quotes in a 30GB+ csv file in python

Tags: python, regex, csv, regex-lookarounds, text-parsing

I have a big file(30GB+) csv where I am counting the number of newlines by parsing the file block by block

Using the below function

```
def yieldblocks(file, size=1024*1024):
    while True:
        blocks = file.read(size)
        if not blocks: break
        yield blocks
```

And calling it so,

```
sum(bl.count("\n") for bl in blocks(txtfile))
```

I am able to count the newlines in slightly under an hour( I am surprised thats the best I could get too )

My problem is I need to skip the new lines coming within double quotes as some columns have multiline content.

I tried the below but it does not seem to be working and process exits without results

```
sum(.5 if re.search('^[^"]*"(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*")*[^"]*$).*$', bl) else 1 for bl in yieldblocks(txtfile))
```

The regular expression is to find odd number of double quotes characters in one line and is working in a small sized file.

I am on a 2GB RAM, 32 bit OS

Note: I tried the CSV module but its slower compared to counting by blocks and was hoping I could somehow get this to work

Comment: What happens if you use `sum(1 for line in file)`?

Comment: Much slower comepared to counting newlines by blocks

Comment: Hate to say it, but this sounds like a job for C. The `block.count('\n')` method could be fast, but it can't deal with quoting. So you have to go through the file byte by byte, tabulating whether you are inside or outside a quote at each point (and remembering as you cross blocks). That will be very slow in Python. You may find that using a memory mapped file helps. You may also be able to use pandas.read_csv (incredibly fast), possibly feeding it chunks via StringIO. But you'll have trouble knowing where to break those chunks (back to the original problem of finding unquoted line endings).

Comment: Just to clarify: What you are *actually* interested in is the number of records in the file?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes please

Answer (score 1):

This may work well for you. `pandas.read_csv` is generally very fast, but I haven't tried it chunk-wise.

```
import pandas as pd
reader = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', chunksize=10000, low_memory=True)
line_count = sum(len(chunk) for chunk in reader)
```

There is a little more info (not much) in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking).

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I tried this. There is an issue in the file that in some lines number of colums headers do not match with count of columns in actual content and pandas doesn’t like that and ignore the lines(if you provide the option to ignore. Else it errors all together ) which will defeat the purpose of counting number of records

Comment: You may need to experiment to see if there's a way around that -- maybe just ask for one column and let it ignore the rest? Otherwise, you may just need to process the whole file byte by byte. As @Danny_ds pointed out, this job may be I/O limited rather than processor limited, so you could just go byte by byte in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way would be to use memory mapping and go over the bytes as follows (pseudo code):

```
bool insidequotes = false

for each byte b:
  if b=='"'
    insidequotes = not insidequotes  // false -> true or true -> false

  else if b=='\n' and not insidequotes
    increment recordcount
```

This should take no longer than the time it would take to copy the file on disk (or even to just read the file) - not sure about the possible overhead in Python.

This also takes care of escaped quotes inside fields:

```
123,test,"24"" monitor",456
```

Comment: Thanks Danny. Does not work since I am on a 32 bit os and I am not able to mmap the file

Comment: @QVSJ Maybe you could mmap blocks of 1GB (not sure about Linux or Python). Or if that doesn't work, just open the file in binary mode and loop through it.